# Mehadrin vs. Non Mehadrin

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

What's the difference between mehadrin and non-mehadrin certifications.

(e.g. at http://www.kosherinjerusalem.com/where_to_eat/kosher-hotels)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be a loaded question, but here goes:

Different kosher organizations can have different standards; the same organization can have two levels of standards, of which one might be "regular kosher" and another "mehadrin" (super-duper) kosher.  E.g. in the page you linked, there are Rabbanut non-mehadrin, and Rabbanut mehadrin.

Often politics can play into things as well, unfortunately, but let's stick strictly with the food.

*If* I recall correctly from [this lecture](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/713654/Rabbi_Dovid_Miller/Kashrut_in_Israel_5766) and elsewhere, here are a few matters that some "non-mehadrin" standards might accept, that "mehadrin" wouldn't. I'm not trying to demonize anyone here; again, as Rabbi Miller said, non-mehadrin is kosher.  To us Americans, some of these are required by our usual standards (OU and the like); some aren't.  I'll refrain from translating or explaining a lot of the jargon below, as I figure the question was intended for audiences with a stronger background.

- "Heter mechira" for Shemita
- Wholesale separation of Trumah (as opposed to doing it again smaller-scale); several decades ago, a few rabbis even employed a heter of R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach's whereby the trumas maaser becomes batel; not sure this is still around anymore.
- How much sifting is required of flour to avoid bugs.
- Relying on USDA or similar supervision to count as Chalav Yisrael (what we call "chalav stam") for powdered (based on the ruling on R' Tzvi Pesach Frank -- but not liquid milk); if you're in Israel this is only an issue for imported products, as most domestic dairy production involves Jews anyhow. With regards to liquid milk, there was an OU mp3 which said some Israeli hechshers are open to the idea of certifying a dairy production as Chalav Yisrael if an overseer is simply watching on video (as opposed to being physically present).
- [In some cases](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/138854), certain forms of animal-derived kosher gelatin.
- Salting the internal cavity of a chicken without splitting it open.
- In the past, freezing meat from South America and only soaking/salting it upon arrival in Israel ("basar kafu").  Though I've heard they now soak/salt it in South America within 72 hours of slaughter anyhow, so this may be moot.

Comment: FYI: The Rabbanut Reishit Yisrael does NOT allow liquid chalav stam .  Most "rabbanut" dairy products are Chalav Yisrael.  Some are made with powdered milk, which orginates from chalav stam, and that is always written on the label.  In this area, the RRY are more machmir than many American kashrus organizations.

Comment: @Will -- thank you. The Rabbi Miller shiur had said it involved issues of CY, but I've recently become aware that rabbanut requires traditional CY with regards to liquid milk -- but not powdered.

Comment: I have seen many products with a rabanut hechsher that says Chalav Nochri on it.

Comment: @Avi, policy may have changed over time (I don't know what rabbanut policy used to be), or they may have been powdered milk (which I know that non-mehadrin allows).

Comment: @Shalom Yeah, I don't know what that news about Hagandaz is about, but when I say I've seen many products, I mean, yesterday. (Or whenever it was this week that I went to the supermarket)

Comment: @avi it doesn't say chalav nochri, it says avakat chalav nochri (or  א. chalav nochri - א stands for avakat, i.e. powdered.)  Additionally, liquid chalav nochri is sold in Israel, but without any rabbanut certification.  American-Israelis who keep kosher will buy imported Philadelphia cream cheese, whereas native kosher keepers won't touch the stuff - it has no endorsement from the Rabbanut.

Comment: Doesn't mehadrin also imply that the meat is glatt?

Comment: @SAH Mehadrin in Kosher-lingo has no formal definition.

Comment: @DoubleAA Right, but wondering why this consideration is not a point on the list, since according to what I've read, "mehadrin" does correlate at least informally with ~glatt

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what @Shalom said, the Rabbanut does not require a *mashgiach temidi* (permanent kashrus supervisor) in restaurants; only a *yotzei v'nichnas* (quasi-random inspections).  This can be a major problem if the owner is not religious, especially for meat restaurants with *basar shenis'alem min ha-ayin* (meat that was not supervised).

Comment: Yes, well Bedatz sends a mashgiach even less often than the Rabanut.  The Rabanut threatened to remove their approval of badatz because of that.

Comment: @avi - Interesting, I didn't know that.  Link to source?

Comment: There are numerous stories told around the streets, but here is one such story told online.  http://muqata.blogspot.com/2009/09/badatz-shmadatz-hevron-wines-are-not.html

Comment: This answer should really include non-anecdotal evidence...

Comment: The bedatz relies on the things than their masgiach being present. They only put their hechsher on a restaurant with religious employees in religious neighborhoods, so they can say that nothing is ever being watched only by people who don't keep kosher, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I also heard, in the name of Rav Miller, that mehadrin vs. non-mehadrin relates to the issue of *rov* as it relates to checking on *shochtim* and whether animals were *shechted* properly. Again, to stress Shalom's point, this is not a matter of Kosher vs. non-Kosher (*rov* is a halachic principle which we can rely on), but a matter of stringency and perhaps for *kashrut* an issue of how you hold on the idea of *timtum ha'lev*...but that is another question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by rov in this context? Either someone is a trusted shochet or not; whether that schochet is check-upon is another issue. Do we not assume that schochetim are trusted... or do they need to be babysat? Is that the difference between mehadrin and non-mehadrin?