# Comprehensive list of Kosher Products

Tags: kashrut-kosher, internet

Is there a comprehensive list on the web of all kosher products?

Comment: Well, you could start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Edible_plants ... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the consensus will be that the answer to your question is 'no'. However, many certifying agencies have lists of all the products they certify, so a comprehensive list of @yydl's item #2 *could* exist by interpolating all of those that are available.

Some of the lists that come to mind are: [OK's](http://www.ok.org/Content.asp?ID=7), [Star-K's](http://www.star-k.org/directory/product_a-z.asp?src=), and [cRc's](http://www.crcweb.org/listsandlinks.php) (also available as [a mobile phone application](http://www.crcweb.org/iApp_release.pdf)).

Answer (score 10):

What you're asking for is **huge**. So huge, I honestly doubt it really exists. Here's why...

You must understand that there are a number of reasons something might be Kosher:

1. It is inherently Kosher (e.g. fruits and vegetables, water, and the like)
2. It is a commercially produced product that has Kosher certification (or one bought in a Kosher-certified store -- but be sure the certification is on the store, if the store is not just reselling it)
3. It is something that was created from other inherently Kosher ingredients by yourself, or your friendly neighbor.

If you really want #1, you can [ask this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for a list of foods that don't require a hechsher. It's actually not that big, but it will be location-dependent. (I may have touched upon it once [over here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7836/safe-foods-in-non-mehadrin-situations))

If you're asking for #2, that would be something you can get from the certifying agency itself. For example, the OU has an [online database](http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/product_search) (although some items are not in it). I don't know about others, but each agency is independent. Which means compiling a full-list would be super-tedious.

And finally #3, depends on your level of trust with said neighbor. And if it's you who's making it: knowing things about not mixing milk-and-meat and the like. For example, when following a recipe you find, recognizing whether it's Kosher or not by looking at the ingredients.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any world list - especially since certain products are kosher in one country but not another - but some countries do keep lists.

Here in England we have a kosher guide and there is a product search online at http://www.theus.org.uk/jewish_living/keeping_kosher/keeping_kosher/kosher_product_search/

Answer (score -1):

I think this can help:

Kosher Register http://kosherregister.com has a comprehensive list of kosher products by categories.

Products: http://www.kosherregister.com/foodproducts/foodproducts.htm

To make your search easier the website has a good search engine of [kosher](http://kosherregister.com) products: by category, year round, kosher for passover, food service and retail.

Comment: −1: of the first three searches I made for products I know to be certified kosher, two found no results and the other yielded a list of agencies as results even though I had searched for products.