# In Israel, what is the difference between l'mehadrin and badatz

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, state-of-israel

In Israel, what is the difference between l'mehadrin and badatz?  Also, is there a regular kosher that is different from these two?

Do they differ with respect to kashrut standards (e.g., require pas yisroel, accept non-cholav Israel milk, require mashgiach temedi for various food establishments)?

Also, has this changed since 2011 when a related question was answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2332) and, if so, how?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2332

Answer (score 2):

Mehadrin is a general term, meaning enhanced/ stricter kashrut. People use it to describe a particular standard, or they might mean a general term for one or several hechsherim (kosher supervisions) e.g. Bedatz Eida Chareidis, Rav Landau, Rav Rubin, Sheeris Yisrael, Rav Machpud etc. The term can also be used by a local rabbinate hechsher to denote a higher level than their usual standard. In other words, it can mean anything or nothing. There is no universal standard. A person needs to ask the specific organization(s) what they mean by mehadrin - this can include not relying on heter mechira, a mashgiach temidi, more careful checking of bugs in vegetables and grains, using "bug free" leafy vegetables, chalav Yisroel, glatt meat, slower and more careful shechita and kashering, using milk only from Shomer Shabbos farms, checking if fruit is orla rather than relying on the majority of that species, etc. etc.

Badatz, as previous posters have mentioned, is the name of several organizations. The Badatz Eida Chareidis, Badatz Mehadrin (Rav Rubin), and others. Again, each has their own standards, and can be asked. Anyone can call themselves "Badatz X" - the word Badatz doesn't mean anything on its own.

Comment: This answer could be improved with real examples

Answer (score 1):

**Mehadrin** (from *hiddur*, meaning "beautified" or "embellished") is the generic term describing a certain level of kashrut, as described [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2333/11501), covering e.g., the presence of a supervisor in a kitchen, the type of meat being served (glatt vs. non-glatt), how shmita is being handled, etc.

**[Badatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badatz)** (acronym of *Beth Din Tsedek*) is a name for a kashrut organization that supervises kosher products. They typically only supervise mehadrin products, this is the case for instance of the most well known Israeli [Badatz Eidat Hacharedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edah_HaChareidis#Kashrus_supervision), Badatz Chassam Sofer from Bnei Brak or Badatz Beit Yosef.

There are other, non-badatz, agencies certifying and requiring mehadrin products, e.g., R Landau in Bnei Brak.

Regular kosher is not mehadrin, by definition. I do not know of a Badatz in Israel who would certify non-mehadrin foods.

Some of the differences between what regular kosher agencies accept and mehadrin don't are halav Israel, shmita heter mechira and no requirement of mashgiach tmidi.

Comment: Can you give some specifics on how they differ with respect to kashrut standards (e.g., require pas yisroael, accept non-cholav milk, do not require mashgiach temedi for various food establishments)? (I clarified the question.)

Comment: What you say differ, I think you are again confusing mehadrin, badatz and non-mehadrin. It is not possible to compare mehadrin and badatz because they are not at the same level. Mehadrin describes a level of kosher (call it "super kosher" for a second) while badatz are some (not all) of the agencies certifying kosher products. In US terms, a badatz would be the equivalent of OU, Kof-K, OK, etc. It happens that badatz apply mehadrin standards but not all have to do necessarily

Comment: Now if you ask about differences between regular kosher and mehadrin, I find the other answer to be still mostly correct for what I know (but I am no deep specialist). For instance, halav Israel is not a requirement of regular kosher, but it is in mehadrin. Heter mechira is fine for regular kosher, not for mehadrin. No mashgiach tmidi required for regular kosher. Hope this helps

Comment: Not all Badatz's are so reliable http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/2008/05/authentic-kosher-certificates/

Comment: "Badatz" alone without speciflying which one,  is generaly refering specificly to the Badattz of the Eida Chareidis, in my experience. So I would asume the quetioner is asking "What is the difference between The Badatz and other hashgachos Refered to as Mehadrin Hashgachos (such as landau, rubin, sheiris....)

Comment: #mbloch, there is no fixed standard for "regular" (rabbanut) kosher in Israel either - each city rabbinate has its own standards - some may not use heter mechira, some may or may not have a mashgiach tmidi (this also depends on type of establishment e.g. a mehadrin vegetable store will probably not have a mashgiach tmidi either, just someone coming once or twice a day to take trumos u'maasros).

Comment: @SamuelManuel  I found this list in an OU booklet from 5774. Is any the group you refer to?
agudat Yisrael – 
Badatz Mehadrin (r’ avraham rubin)  
Beit Yosef – 
Belz – Machzikei hadas –  
chatam sofer Bnei Brak –  
chatam sofer petach Tikvah –  
chief rabbinate Fraud division – 
chief rabbinate import division – R’Yitzchak HaCohen Arazi 
 efrati, rabbi Yosef Kashrut l’Mehadrin –
eida chareidit 
eida chareidit sephardi –
Jerusalem rabbinate Kashrut dept 
Kehillat Ye’rei’im – 
landau, r’Yehuda leib (Bnei Brak) –
nvei Tzion –
oKisrael-
ou israel –
sheirit Yisrael –
Yoreh deah (rav Machpud) –

Comment: "They typically only supervise mehadrin products". Not true. Badatz, as you point out, is an acronym for Beit Din Tzedek. Everyone has a Beit din that does their certifications. The rabbanuts non-Mehadrin hecksher is also done by their Beit din, and the certificates say Badatz on them - because they're done by the Beit Din of the rabbanut.

Comment: @YehudaW I dont understand what you're asking.

Comment: @SamuelManuel Are you referring to my original question or to one of my comments above?

Comment: @YehudaW your comment on may 2