# Badatz and Mehadrin Kashrut

Tags: kashrut-kosher

If something is marked Badatz Chatam Sofer or mehadrin, would it be considered Chalav Yisroel and Pas Yisroel?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll be on the label if it's chalav yisoel and pas yisroel.

Comment: relevant: [In Israel, what is the difference between l'mehadrin and badatz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70846/11501) and [Mehadrin vs. Non Mehadrin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2332/11501)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Anyone can mark something "mehadrin" and standards may differ.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to ask the certifying authority or your local Rabbi. Those items that are chalav Yisroel that I have seen will have chalav Yisroel added to the label. Something could be marked mehadrin but still be Chalav Stam.

Comment: Also different people may have different understandings of what constitutes chalav yisrael

Answer (score 0):

In the US they use the letter D to designate a product as Dairy but not CY. In Israel, the general policy of **ALL** the MeHadrin kashrut services **DO NOT** certify products that are Chalav Stam /Nochri from non-Jewish sources.  The Chief Rabbinate of Israel allows Avkat Chalav Nochri (non-Jewish milk powder) in many of their products which are marked with Chalav Nochri. Rabbis Amar & Shtern, Chief Rabbis of Jerusalem allow Avkat Chalav Nochri in baked goods (bakery in Hadassah Hospital, Ein Kerem.)  If a product is marked Pat Yisrael, in general it is Pat Yisrael.

Comment: So, to directly address the OP’s question: if it doesn’t have any of these special markings and just has the Badatz or Mehadrin labels, is it presumed Chalav/Pas Yisrael?